# Magento 2.3 Convert Quote from store to another store

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, multistore, quote, multicurrency

I need to convert a quote from one store in GBP to another website store in EUR dynamically on the fly, but i can save the item with the new store_Id and the quote with the correct store_id but collectTotals is not recalculating to get the store level prices.

```
       $quote = $this->quoteRepository->getActive($cartId);

        $quote->setStore($store);

        $items =  $this->quoteRepository->getActive($cartId)->getAllItems();
        foreach($items as $item)
        {
            $item = $quote->getItemById($item->getId());
            $item->setData('store_id',$storeId);
            $item->calcRowTotal();
            $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
            $item->save();
        }

        $quote->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false)->collectTotals()->save();
```

Any advice? Or any ideas would be appreciated.